# App Crashing at LayoutInflater [on MIUI Devices]

Tags: android

I have deployed an Android Application and Crash Reports indicate that the app is unable to launch on MIUI devices. I am getting a Layout Exception in MainActivity. Added Crash report:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2200)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2249)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800 (ActivityThread.java:141)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1212)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:136)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5113)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:796)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:612)
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (Native Method)
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView (LayoutInflater.java:623)
      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView (PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView (LayoutInflater.java:672)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:697)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:758)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:495)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:400)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:353)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView (AppCompatActivity.java:139)
      at com.studio.sanjeev.shhsilence.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.java:76)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:5242)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1087)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2164)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: 
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative (Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Constructor.java:423)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView (LayoutInflater.java:597)
    Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: 
      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable (Resources.java:2139)
      at android.content.res.MiuiResources.loadDrawable (MiuiResources.java:393)
      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable (Resources.java:2062)
      at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable (TypedArray.java:602)
      at android.view.View.<init> (View.java:3558)
      at android.widget.TextView.<init> (TextView.java:623)
      at android.widget.Button.<init> (Button.java:107)
      at android.widget.CompoundButton.<init> (CompoundButton.java:68)
      at android.widget.ToggleButton.<init> (ToggleButton.java:51)
      at android.widget.ToggleButton.<init> (ToggleButton.java:64)
    Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: 
      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable (Resources.java:2139)
      at android.content.res.MiuiResources.loadDrawable (MiuiResources.java:393)
      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable (Resources.java:2062)
      at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable (Resources.java:710)
      at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate (StateListDrawable.java:176)
      at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner (Drawable.java:939)
      at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml (Drawable.java:879)
      at android.content.res.Resources.createFromXml (Resources.java:2515)
      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable (Resources.java:2135)
    Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: 
      at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner (Drawable.java:935)
      at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml (Drawable.java:879)
      at android.content.res.Resources.createFromXml (Resources.java:2515)
      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable (Resources.java:2135)
```

Line 76 on MainActivity is

```
73: @Override
74: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
75:    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
76:    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

I have researched LayoutInflater and mostly it arises in Out of Memory cases whereas there is no such issue for my activity_main. I am using a vector drawable image in a toggle button:

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/power"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:textOff=""
    android:textOn=""
    android:background="@drawable/check"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/adView"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

check is a selector as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/poweron"
        android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/poweroff"
        android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

I want to figure out what exactly is affecting MIUI users of my app and how to fix it as soon as possible.

Comment: are `poweron` and `poweroff` in drawable folder ?

Comment: `Resources$NotFoundException`... Is it a vector Drawable?

Comment: @ThomasMary Yes, they are in the folder. Infact application is running fine on non-MIUI devices.

Comment: @cricket_007 yep, poweron and poweroff are vector drawables

Comment: Are you able to use `app:srcCompat`? https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html#about

Comment: @cricket_007 No, I am unable to use srcCompat. I came across this solution earlier too and tried it. The application crashed on all devices with same log.

Comment: What is your API Level ?

Comment: @ThomasMary My API level is 22 (5.1.1). Target SDK version is API 26(Oreo). Just FYI, Most of the crash affected users have an API level 19 (KitKat)